# What is the name for the unique "simplification" of a graph?

Tags: graph-theory, definition

Is there a conventional name for the resultant graph (H) obtained by deleting all loops and multiple edges from the original graph (G)?

Something along the lines of "Let H be the **simple graph** of G.." or "Let H be the **simplified version** of G.." where I would like to replace the boldfaced. (The former doesn't sound quite correct, while the latter is worse.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is universal, but $H$ is sometimes referred to as the *underlying simple graph* of $G$. For example, this terminology is used in [Bondy and Murty](http://books.google.ca/books?id=HuDFMwZOwcsC&pg=PA48&lpg=PA48&dq=underlying%20simple%20graph&source=bl&ots=xIohuzXUJZ&sig=l7FvYPiHDuyxm7WNnT6T3_mD_X0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=AElkUcKXK6a-0QGJqIH4AQ&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=underlying%20simple%20graph&f=false). An analogous term is often used for digraphs when referring to the *underlying undirected graph* of a digraph.

Comment: Thanks for your heads-up. Sounds better than my suggestions already.